# Make duplicate close votes more obvious

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I read a question and I think "this is a great question!" Then I see there's a close vote or two, but I ignore it because I think the question is a good one....  However, the reason people want to close the question is that it's a duplicate of a previous excellent question.

This doesn't happen in the close votes review queue because there I am informed that people want to close it because it's a duplicate. I wish there were a feature to provide this information outside of the queue without requiring a click.

Comment: Well, usually you'll notice the "possible duplicate:" in the comments below the post.  Also, close votes on a high quality post are usually duplicate votes, so it's just something you learn to check for.

Answer (score 3):

There is an automatic comment added by the 1st user who voted to close saying something along the lines of:

> Possible duplicate: `<duplicate link>`

That comment is automagically removed when the question is closed.

Comment: unless that link has already been posted in a previous comment.

Comment: @Servy even so, you will see the possible duplicate comment.

Comment: If someone writes, "This has nothing to do with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159345/" no auto generated possible dupe comment will be added for that link.

Comment: Oh, and the auto generated comment can be manually deleted by the person who cast the first dup vote, if we want to mention edge cases.

Comment: @Servy `Bahh!!`